# Android ArrayAdapter Error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

Here is my code.
I am getting error while I am trying to reach my query results.

> (07-04 08:31:01.811: E/CursorWindow(5090): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 3 columns.).

I really don't know how can I handle it. 
Thanks for your help.

```
private void Bul(String CepTEL) {
    try
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search.this,
                            android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        String[] sutunlar= {"NAME","LASTNAME","JOB","BDAY","ADDRESS","EMAIL","MOBILETEL","HOMETEL","WORKTEL"};
        SQLiteDatabase db= v1.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor okunanlar=db.query("CUSTOMER",sutunlar,"MOBILETEL=?", new String[] {CepTEL},null,null,null);
        String NAME="";
        String LASTNAME="";
        String JOB="";
        String BDAY="";
        String ADDRESS="";
        String EMAIL="";
        String MOBILETEL="";
        String HOMETEL="";
        String WORKTEL="";

        while(okunanlar.moveToFirst())
        {
            NAME=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(NAME));
            LASTNAME=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(LASTNAME));
            JOB=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(JOB));
            BDAY=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(BDAY));
            ADDRESS=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(ADDRESS));
            EMAIL=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
            MOBILETEL=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(MOBILETEL));
            HOMETEL=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(HOMETEL));
            WORKTEL=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex(WORKTEL));     
            ArrayAdapter2.add(NAME+"\n"+LASTNAME+"\n"+JOB+"\n"+BDAY+"\n"+ADDRESS+"\n"+EMAIL+"\n"+MOBILETEL+"\n"+HOMETEL+"\n"+WORKTEL);
        }
        cekilenleriGoster(ArrayAdapter2);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bilgiler girilirken hata oluştu.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }               
}
```

Comment: You're trying to access the data of the `Cursor` using the index of a column which has as the name an **empty** string.

Comment: oh thanks.                        NAME=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("NAME")); It must be like that and it works.